# Sinatra: Routes that do not route

Tags: jquery, routes, sinatra

My Sinatra webapp has a list of articles which can be deleted by the users. I've added a jQuery animation to make the deleted articles fade away before the actual (DB) deletion is carried out by a Sinatra route. The code is elementary:

```
# script.js
$(".lnk-delete").click(function()
  {
    var id = $(this).closest("article").attr("id");
    $("#"+id).fadeToggle(1000);
  });

# app.rb
get '/delete/articles/:id' do
    Articles.get(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect to('/')
end
```

The problem is, the code reroutes to the same page, which is now unnecessary since the deleted article is no longer showing. Not only the reroute generates unnecessary load, it also brings the user back to the top of the page (making the experience confusing and annoying).

I have looked around, tried returning HTTP codes, tried halt(ing), tried the request.xhr function and anything else I could find online, all to no avail...

Is there a way to make the route "not route", i.e. execute the db.destroy and leave the actual page "unrefreshed"?

### Update

The following code, a slightly modified version of @exobrain's answer, solved my problem.

```
# script.js
$(".lnk-delete").click(function(clicked) {
    clicked.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest("article").attr("id"); $("#"+id).fadeToggle(1000); 
    $.get($(this).children("a").attr("href"));
});
```

Three things changed in my original code:

1. Added `preventDefault` to the script so as to prevent the link being followed;
2. The link request is now done by jQuery, using `get`;
3. The Sinatra route was modified so it no longer redirects to '/'.

Here's the code:

```
# app.rb
get '/delete/articles/:id' do
    Articles.get(params[:id]).destroy
end
```

As a note to beginners (as myself), this `get` route is inconsistent with best practices. It should be a `delete` route. I'll fix that, eventually.

Thanks, @exobrain & @Amadan, for the answers.

---

P.S.:

Fixed the `get` route. All it took was changing

```
$.get($(this).children("a").attr("href"));
```

to

```
$.ajax({ url: $(this).children("a").attr("href"), type: "delete"});
```

and then `get '/delete/articles/:id' do` to `delete '/delete/articles/:id' do` on the actual Sinatra application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit odd to be using a `get` request to delete a resource, but none-the-less, you can do this using ajax. I'm assuming `.link-delete` is an `a` tag, and has a `href` attribute pointing to the Sinatra endpoint. The following code will stop the link from being followed through by the browser (`preventDefault`), then perform an AJAX `get` request to the url pointed to by the link. When the request completes and returns, the fadeout is performed in the callback.

```
$(".lnk-delete").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("article").attr("id");
    $("#"+id).fadeToggle(1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Erm... Yeah... That get is yet another issue to tackle. I tried using the data-method of the <a> tag but the request was still being passed as a get request. I read something about Sinatra's :method_override config which I might try later in order to fix that. Regarding the issue at hand, thank you for the code fragment. It did not quite work - apparently the preventDefault() was not triggered and I got a blank page on completion - but that is OK. With your answer and @Amadan's I can progress a bit more. I will look into the AJAX request and rewrite the code. Thanks heaps!

Comment: It is not odd, it is dangerous. It can be collected by GoogleBot, which means it can wipe your whole database if it can access a page with the delete links. GET requests should not be able to change anything on the server aside from incidentals like logging. For any change, you should do POST, PUT or DELETE (none of which you can get from a plain `<a>`: POST can be done with a form, and all three can be done in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

If you're submitting to `/delete/articles/...` via AJAX, the actual page will remain unrefreshed. (You have not shown the submit code.) You can simply return `""` from your controller instead of the redirect for a blank body.

If you're not using AJAX, then the fadeout is superfluous; you will need that redirect.

Comment: The submit code is just a html <a> tag with an url pointing to /delete/articles/:id (where :id has already been replaced with the article's id). The fadeout works as I expected, so it's not exactly superfluous. I just didn't want the page to reload. But if I understand your answer correctly, I will need to code this by submitting via AJAX if I want it to work. Thanks for your suggestion, Amadan.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a redirect, use a [`halt`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting) at the end of the route with the [correct status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). You should also get rid of that GET as you've been advised.

```
get '/delete/articles/:id' do
    Articles.get(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect to('/')
end
```

becomes

```
get '/articles/:id' do
  # get the article here
end

delete '/articles/:id' do
  Articles.get(params[:id]).destroy
  halt 200
  # I'd also return a representation of the deleted article
  # or perhaps it's ID
  # but maybe that's just me
end
```

HTTP has verbs for a reason. Don't use `$.get`, use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and pass it the correct verb i.e. DELETE. See *Type* in the link.

Notice that the verb no longer needs to be in the URL as well.